# reduce code duplication using macros

Tags: c++

I was wondering if someone out there could give me a pointer to reducing duplication when coding.

im required to call a function a number of times to populate a structure, for example:

```
typedef struct {
    uint16_t u16_a;
    bool b_org;
    char* c_c;
    uint16_t u16_d;

} TEntry;
```

I need to populate each value of these with a function call, although the return values vary, the same function is used for all. 
Would a macro be sufficient to create a template in some way, so that the return type would be dependent on the specific parameter ("string")

for example:

```
Trrelevant::Trrelevant()
{
    TPoint* u_apoint = Insufficient::FindValue("A");
    if (u_bpoint != NULL) {
        int a = u_apoint;
    }

    TPoint* p_apoint = Insufficient::FindValue("borg");
    if (p_bpoint != NULL) {
        bool b = p_bpoint;
    }


    TPoint* p_cpoint = Insufficient::FindValue("C");
    if (etc != NULL) {
        char* c = etc;
    }

    TEct* etc = Insufficient::FindValue("ETC");
    if (etc != ETC) {
        etc = etc;
    }

    TEntry entry = {a,
                    b,
                    c,
                    etc};
}
```

this code is not compiled or accurate, im just trying to illustrate. Im weak in C++ and new to macros, but would anyone know a way to have a macro solve this?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Best option, don't. Macros have no sense of context or type safety.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about code length in this case

Comment: Maybe `Insufficient::FindValue` could return a `boost::variant`?

Comment: Thank you for your opinion, I just got bored using functions I want to see if a macro is capable, and how so

Comment: @sam, thats true in this case, but the above code is just illustration, I need it on a larger scale, for example, if that struct was larger, etc

Comment: @Irrelevant shove all the ugly long code in a corner, and hide it behind a method call.  problem solved!

Comment: Create an array/list for ("borg","C","ETC") and also default value for Find result, then go with a loop?

Comment: The above code looks suspicious. How can the same function return different types? (It can, but for that it needs to be a member function in an inheritance hierarchy and `FindValue` isn't.)

Comment: "this code is not compiled or accurate, im just trying to illustrate", the final return value obtained through this call, (which in reality goes through another interface) will return a different value based on the char sequence passed in, e.g."A" = uint16_t

Comment: Get it working before you worry about getting it simpler.  A single function cannot change its return type (a compile-time value) based on the contents of a `const char*` expression (a run-time value).  And the example right now is too vague for us to know what it is you're even trying to do.

Comment: Are you definitely need a macros? I think it would be easier to use templates, something like `template<typename T> T FindValue(const std::string &key, const T &defaultValue)`.

Comment: In your example code, what do you expect to happen when you assign values of type Tpoint* to uint16_t variables? (or, after your last edit, to int or bool variables? P.S. a, b, c are not visible where you use them.

Comment: I want to keep the information, and put it into a list of my struts, like in the above example "entry"

Comment: Assigning a pointer, which you already checked not to be NULL, to a bool certainly doesn't keep much information. The bool will always be true. In short: your example doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this, although I don't know what it really buys you.

```
#define QuickFindValue(NAME, TYPE, FUNCTION)             \
     TYPE *NAME##Value = Insufficient::FindValue(#NAME); \
     if (NAME##Value == NULL) { FUNCTION; }
```

You would use it like so:

```
QuickFindValue(C, TPoint, { 
  char *c = CValue;
  // Do stuff..
});
```

Comment: Thank you Nathan for that, so what if you had a mapping for the #NAME and the return type it provided, would it be possible to support #TYPE to #NAME mapping also? or best to do this outside of the macro,

Comment: So you want to be able to map NAME to return TYPE? You could build off the first macro and add two quicker macros like so: #define QuickFindValueETC(FUNCTION) QuickFindValue(ETC, TEtc, FUNCTION) #define QuickFindValueA(FUNCTION) QuickFindValue(A, TPoint, FUNCTION)

Comment: The other thing you can do, is if you name your TYPEs consistently, so that "C" always has a return type of TC or "ETC" always has a return type of TETC, etc... you can construct the return type based on T##NAME. And that would remove the need for the second TYPE parameter.

Comment: Thats excellent, I failed to see this before, thank you Nathan :)

Comment: This is a good starting resource on macros. http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/gcc-3.0.2/html_chapter/cpp_3.html. See sections stringification and concatenation.

Comment: Thank you for this! it does look like a gold mine for what im seeking at the minute, very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had the same kind of issue, I'm not sure what kind of source you use for your inputs.
Personnaly, I used XML as input.
Then I have A Builder class that parses the XML call a factory funciton to build every struct in the c++ using the data from the parser.

I don't think that MACRO or templtes would be of any help (or it would be a bad solution).
Note that an external resource (like xml) is nice if ever you want to change without recompiling.

Best

Comment: Thanks Ill keep xml or a function in mind if I cant reach a solution